# What is the performance impact of the order property in the Index Attribute using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to know what the performance impact of this property is:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute.order(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Profile it in your specific use case. It also depends on what database you're running it against.

Comment: I use Azure SQL database in Azure mobile services.

Comment: Great, then you should connect to it with SQL management studio, get the queries EF produces and benchmark those against your data.

Answer (score 1):

This attribute simply specifies which columns come in what order in a multi-column index.  There is no performance impact one way or the other directly due to the attribute.

Whether having a multi-column index is better for your use case than not having it depends on too many factors to cover here.  If you think performance would benefit from having the multi-column index, use it.